# Path filtering recognizing changes but not executing workflow

Tags: github-actions, cicd

So I'm using `dorny/paths-filter@v2` to check for changes in certain files and execute a specific workflow when changes are recognized. The workflow looks like this.

```
changes:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    outputs:
      backend: ${{ steps.changes.outputs.backend }}
      ecr: ${{ steps.changes.outputs.ecr }}
      lambda: ${{ steps.changes.outputs.lambda }}
    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v3
    - uses: dorny/paths-filter@v2
      id: changes
      with:
        base: ${{ github.ref }}
        filters: |
          ecr:
            - 'terraform_ecr/**'
          backend:
            - 'scraper_backend/**'
            - 'app.py'
            - 'tagging.sh'
            - 'Dockerfile'
          lambda:
            - 'terraform_lambda/**'
```

This is a job called changes where I look for changes for 3 different steps. I use these if statements to check if a change was recognized.

```
ecr:
    needs: [changes, setup]
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    if: ${{ needs.changes.outputs.ecr == 'true' }}
```

For ecr

```
backend:
    needs: [changes, setup, ecr]
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    if: ${{ needs.changes.outputs.backend == 'true' }}
```

for backend

```
lambda:
    needs: [changes, setup, ecr, backend]
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    if: ${{ needs.changes.outputs.lambda == 'true' }}
```

for lambda

I also test the outputs in my changes job like this.

```
- name: test backend
      run: |
        echo ${{ steps.changes.outputs.backend }}
    - name: test ecr
      run: |
        echo ${{ steps.changes.outputs.ecr }}
    - name: test lambda
      run: |
        echo ${{ steps.changes.outputs.lambda }}
```

And when I for example make a change in a file in `scraper_backend` it does print 'true' as you can see in a screenshot beneath.

[![backend true value][1]][1]

But my workflow skipped this step. See next picture.

[![workflow steps][2]][2]

I was thinking might this have to do something with this `base` parameter im using?

```
steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v3
    - uses: dorny/paths-filter@v2
      id: changes
      with:
        base: ${{ github.ref }} # <------- this line
        filters: |
          ecr:
            - 'terraform_ecr/**'
          backend:
            - 'scraper_backend/**'
            - 'app.py'
            - 'tagging.sh'
            - 'Dockerfile'
          lambda:
            - 'terraform_lambda/**'
```

I used this to check against the latest commit. But on a `pull-request` this gets ignored and then i can see that all steps are runned. All help is greatly appreciated!
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xkI5s.png
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/vKAsA.png